# Javascript Function not working in firefox or safari

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the sum of transaction at the bottom of the page.

```
function doTotal() {
    var Stuff = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var theTotal = new Number(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < Stuff.length; i++) {
        if (Stuff[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            if ((Stuff[i].value != '') && (IsNumeric(Stuff[i].value) == true) && (Stuff[i].name.substr(0, 8) == 'txtValue')) {
                theTotal = theTotal + parseFloat(Stuff[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("tdTotal").innerHTML = "R " + theTotal.toFixed(2);
    frm.txtTotal.value = theTotal.toFixed(2);
    //alert(theTotal);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: <TR>
 <TD colspan=4 align=right>TOTAL:<Input type="hidden" name="txtTotal" id="txtTotal" value=0></TD>
 <TD id="tdTotal"></TD>
</TR>

Comment: Response.Write "<TD align=right><Input size=8 name=""txtValue_" & intX & """ id=""txtValue_" & intX & """ value=0 onKeyPress=""javascript: return checkNumeric(event)"" onChange=""javascript: doTotal();"">"

Comment: Not working is quite vague. How it misbehaves? Do you have incorrect total? It won't fire at all? It throws an error (and what)? Have you tried to call the function via the javascript console (you can execute it step by step)?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Ofc Im stupid, it cant work since value from input is always string. So I change the condition. Now it should work:

```
function doTotal() {
    var stuff = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var theTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
        if (stuff[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            if ((stuff[i].value != '') && !isNaN(stuff[i].value) && (typeof stuff[i].name.substr(0, 8) === "string")) {
                theTotal += parseFloat(stuff[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    // document.getElementById("tdTotal").innerHTML = "R " + theTotal.toFixed(2);
    // frm.txtTotal.value = theTotal.toFixed(2);
    alert(theTotal);
}
```

Try it there: http://jsfiddle.net/windkiller/9dvRS/

**EDIT2:**

Debug it, so you can see what condition didnt pass wrong:

function doTotal() {
        var stuff = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var theTotal = 0;

```
        var i = 0;

        alert(stuff[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text');
        alert(stuff[i].value != '');
        alert(!isNaN(stuff[i].value));
        alert(typeof stuff[i].name.substr(0, 8) === "string");
}
```

Comment: I tested this in my firefox+G chrome and it works (alerts sum of numbers I fill into inputs on any page). Are you sure that your javascript is not cached or something?